# HTTP Status 500 - can't instantiate DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Yet again another

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Please could you guys (those of you who understand it) write a guide to help us debug this ? What does it even mean ? What could make it not able to instantiate that class ?

Anyways I have a headache. I'm only having 1 controller and one default dispatcher servlet with `/` url pattern. Still it fails with tha HTTP 500... I'm even wondering it at all the servlet goes into the `component-scan base package`. Below is my project architecture and a few codes :

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- BASIC DEPENDENCIES -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!-- CURRENT JDK -->

  <properties>    
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DefaultServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

defaultServlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.parochia.controllers" /> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/ressources/theme1/" /> 
</beans>
```

**the controller**

```
@Controller
public class liturgieController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String liturgie(Model model){
        return "liturgie";
    }
}
```

**PS : ** Please friends, there is too many of this error here. We can't even scan the other responses and apply it to our cas as it seems to be different every time it happens. How should we debug this before even coming to stackoverflow. What does it even mean..

... I'm frustrated :(

Comment: I dunno but could `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` help. In `web.xml` when declaring the servlet.

Comment: in your `web.xml` you have written "DefaultServlet-context.xml" but maybe there should be a lowercase "d" in the start? (just shooting in the dark). There can also be a mix of Spring versions or any number of reasons why it doesn't work. xml-configuration is tricky.

Comment: @JackFlamp Nope. I've copy/paste to avoid typo mistakes. All names match. It was driving me crazy yesterday. lol. Anyways,  don't waste your time with this. I just gave up and created a new project.

Answer (score -1):

In servlet definitions in `web.xml` replace `<sevlet-mapping>/<sevlet-mapping>` by

```
<sevlet-mapping>/*<sevlet-mapping>
```

and send other exception s to see.

Comment: same result. I'm just going to give up and start a new project... because it does not make sense..Thanks for looking into it

Comment: if you're going to start a new project, please consider using Spring Boot which handles a lot of this basic wiring for you already.

Comment: @Ben Yeah I know spring boot. But I want to understand spring...soo I won't use it this time. And by the way, I started a new project. Same configuration and it works fine. Some times technology is not so messy....

Comment: so the setup does work? Why won't you just use the new project instead? Sometimes things just don't work for no apparent reason.

Comment: @JackFlamp  Yeah I gave up and I started using the new project. DId not change any of the logic I used before but now it works...